# c# class variable type another class

Tags: c#, class, variables

i have a two class. Product and Color. how to access ProductColor(name,id) sample :

```
public class tblColor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
}

 public class Urun
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public tblRenk ProductColor { get; set; }
}

while (dr.Read())
{
    products.Add(new Product()
    {
        ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"].ToString()),
        ProductName = dr["ProdName"].ToString(),
        ?????? ProductColor  = dr["ColName"].ToString() 
    });
}
```

Comment: Wait.. i think im being noob here.. why is it not Urun.Add(new Urun(){ProductId = intVal, ProductName = stringVal, ProductColor = tblRenkVal});

Comment: so, ProductColor contain : Colorid and ColorName. one variable two value...

Comment: Do not use hungarian notation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `ProductColor` itself to a new instance:

```
ProductColor = new Color()
```

You will probably want to initialize its properties with a nested `{ ... }` block.

Comment: i dont understand. sory. can you write on my code please.. thanks

Comment: @SLaks, `ProductColor` is of type `tblColor`, how can they assign a `new Color()`?

Comment: solved. Wrote one, but now does not seem the answer. Again, thank you.

Comment: ProductColor = new tblColor() { ColorName = dr["ColName"].ToString() },

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: `Color` is a poor type name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the class with the property in it and then call it.  in your case, you would do:

```
Product p = new Product();
```

From there you could call the property in Product to be used in Color:

```
p.SomeColor = some variable you set in the Color class;
```